# How to make the character move down to platform when swiped down on the screen

Tags: swipe, unity-game-engine

I have a character that is running when I swipe up it jumps, and after certain time it comes back automatically to the ground. I need to add the change like while jumping if I swipe down it should  come down soon at that instant itself.

```
private Vector3 fp;   
private Vector3 lp;  
private float dragDistance; 
private List<Vector3> touchPositions = new List<Vector3>(); 


foreach (Touch touchi in Input.touches) 

{                           
    if (touchi.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        touchPositions.Add(touchi.position);
    }

    if (touchi.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {                       
        fp =  touchPositions[0];
        lp =  touchPositions[touchPositions.Count-1];

        if (Mathf.Abs (lp.x - fp.x) > dragDistance 
                 || Mathf.Abs (lp.y - fp.y) > dragDistance) 
        {
            if (lp.y > fp.y) 
            {
                jumpSpeed = 0;
                enabled = InAir();              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code but its not working,think some mistake in sencing the touch even print does not work in side foreach.

Comment: where does this foreach loop exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a nice snippet to handle swipe:

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
    {
        Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;
        if(touchDeltaPosition.y < 0)
        {
            //move character down here
        }
    }
}
```

[Learn More](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)